# casting void pointer in the same variable leads to compilation error

Tags: c, pointers

I'm testing an issue that I'm having when casting void pointers to a different type within the same variable. The issue seems to be when trying to use the same variable for the casted pointer. Below I have a section of code that tests this. Would someone be able to tell me why the program fails to compile for that case?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test {

  int a;

}test;

int main() {

  void * check;
  test * check2;
  check =  malloc(sizeof(test));

  check = ((test *) check);
  check2 = (test *)check;


  check->a = 2; //this raises an error (dereferencing void pointer) when compiling
  check2->a = 2; //this works
  ((test *)check)->a = 2; //this also works
}
```

Comment: You cannot dereference  (i.e. apply operator `*` or operator `->` to) a void pointer.

Comment: Do you think that `check = ((test *) check);` changes the _type_ of `check`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Why would that not change the type of check?

Comment: Because the type of an object is determined by its declaration, not by any value that might be assigned to it later. This: `check = ((test *) check);` explicitly converts the value of `check` from `void*` to `test*`, and then implicitly, via the assignment, converts the result right back to `void*`. Similarly, `int n; n = 2.5;` doesn't result in `n` being able to hold fractional values; it's still an `int`.

Comment: `check = ((test *) check);` does nothing. Your compiler probably will optimize it away

Comment: Changing types is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a pointer is just lying to your compiler

```
void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(test));
((test *)ptr)->a = 5;
```

In the second line, we are telling the compiler *"I know I declared ptr as a (void *), but I'm smarter than you, and trust me, it's actually a (test *)"*. Nothing has changed, ptr is still just a pointer, an address of a memory location, but the compiler assumes it's pointing to something specific.

```
  check->a = 2; //this raises an error (dereferencing void pointer) when compiling
```

You **must** cast your variables every single time you want the compiler to treat it as something different from what you declared it to be.

A more interesting scenario to explain what you can do with casting pointers...

```
// struct with two ints, a and b
typedew struct testAB {
  int a;
  int b;
} testAB;

// struct with two ints, named in reverse order
typedef struct testBA {
  int b;
  int a;
} testBA;

int main(void) {
  // construct a testAB struct
  void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(testAB));
  ((testAB *)ptr)->a = 0
  ((testAB *)ptr)->b = 1

  // treat ptr as a testBA struct
  if ( ((testBA *)ptr)->a == 1) {
    printf("this shouldn't happen, 'a' was set to 0");
  }
}
```

if you run the above code, you will find that the printf statement will be executed. Even though we set 'a' to be 0, and the if statement checks that a == 1.

This is because structs are stupidly simple. In the above example the struct(s) is just two int's packed next to eachother. Much like an array of two ints, like this:

```
int array[2] = {0, 1};
void *ptr = &array;
```

Even with this representation, we can lie to the compiler, we can force the compiler to treat this 'array' as one of our structs.

```
if ( ((testAB *)array)->a == 0 )
  printf("a is 0");
```

This is because, under the hood, the compiler treats named variables in a struct as just offests from where the struct is.

```
// the following two lines have the same affect
((testAB *)array)->a = 0;
array[0] = 0;

// the following two lines have the same affect
((testAB *)array)->b = 2;
array[1] = 2;
```

if we tell the compiler that it's a (testAB *), then 'a' means the first int, and 'b' means the second. If we tell the compiler that it's a (testBA *), then 'a' is the second, and 'b' is the first.

In compiled code **ALL** variable names are lost. The compiler reduces the struct assignment, down to "set the second int of the struct to 2". Or more specifically, if we are dealing with 32-bit ints, set bytes 5, 6, 7 and 8 of the struct to 0000, 0000 0000 0010 (in binary. (or perhaps in reverse order, if we are compiling for a little endian CPU)